# PHP: Define class alias inside class or in the same file as class

Tags: php

Can I define the class alias inside the class, or, at least, in the same file as class?

Currently, I can not import the `References` class as `RF`:

**Class file:**

```
class_alias('References', 'RF');

class References {

    // ...

}
```

**Other file:**

```
use App\Extenders\References;

class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {

        Schema::create(RF::tables // ...
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `use App\Extenders\References as RF;` instead?

Comment: Just because I did not know about `as` :)

Comment: Oh! Well try that, it should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will do it, but to close this question 'This is possible by this way:' or 'No, it's impossible' answer required.

Comment: I've never used `class_alias();` to be honest. Did you try putting `class_alias('References', 'RF');` on the `CreateOrdersTable` page under the `use`?

Comment: ... sorry, it will be the the off-top. We considering 'inside class or in the same file as class'.